# NestJS nested object validation is showing validation error even when nested object is correct

Tags: nestjs

I have a nested DTO class to validate the networking.

Here is my DTO class:

```js
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsIP, IsNotEmpty, IsOptional, IsString, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

export class IpAddressRequest {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @IsIP()
  public address?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  public netmask?: string;

  constructor(address?: string, netmask?: string) {
    this.address = address;
    this.netmask = netmask;
  }
}

export class CreateRouteRequest {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @IsIP()
  gateway: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(({ value }) => {
    return new IpAddressRequest(value.destination?.address, value.destination?.netmask);
  })
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  destination?: IpAddressRequest;
}
```

My `expectation` is:

While I will pass an object like this as the request payload, it should succeed:

```json
{
  "gateway": "<some-valid-ip-address",
  "destination": {
    "address": "10.10.10.20"
  }
}
```

However I am getting the validation error at the `destination.address` field as follows:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "destination.address must be an ip address",
    "destination.address must be a string",
    "destination.address should not be empty"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

But my request payload is correct (per my expectation).

How to make such a nested object validation works for nest js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `CreateRouteRequest` class, you are applying transform on the `destination` property. Hence, you should write `value?.address` instead of `value.destination?.address` when invoking the constructor.